# Wasting time trying to build python web apps

Tags: python, sql, configuration, flask

I learning Python to build a CMS/calendar/schedule app and I know a decent amount of SQL and HTML. As I'm learning, I'm running into new tools/frameworks (bottle, SQLAlchemy, WTForms) and I have to reset.

I'm wasting time continuing to download, test, learn a bit of this and that and then scrap the database/project and start over.

My site has a few requirements:

- An SQL database (PostgreSQL or MSSQL or MYSQL) provided I can have encrypted data on some tables (PII). I'm indifferent as to which.
- SSL support
- Login support with groups, users, etc.
- Ability to support at ~500 concurrent users.
- Deploy via dedicated server using lighttpd or even Apache
- Ability to have production site hosted via expensive/quality provider

What modules/packages should I use to accomplish this?  Am I on the right track with Python, Flask, SQLAlchemy, WTForms(needed?)  ?

Perhaps another way to ask - if I was to sit at your desk, what would be your setup to accomplish this project?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions involving "what do you use" or "what do you recommend" aren't a good fit for this site, as there are many possible correct answers and tend to lead to discussion and polling (see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)). Having said that, I would recommend Django or Pylons.

Answer (score 2):

Try out [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). It's the most mature and feature-rich web framework available for Python. There are lots of plugins for it as well, if you need some functionality that Django doesn't provide out-of-the-box. If you don't get happy with Django, you should maybe switch to another language. But Django is great, give it a try.

Comment: Pedantic note: I don't know that I'd call Django a language.  A *framework* definitely, but it's not the only framework in the Python ecosystem ;-)

Comment: @SeanVieira You misunderstand me. What I mean is: "If you don't get happy with Django, you should maybe switch to a language _other than Python because Django is the best web framework for Python and if it cannot accomplish what you want to do, then you should take a look at a different language with different frameworks (such as Ruby on Rails)_".

Comment: @permistahl, hahaha, i found you on SO!! ahahahaha, BTW, the next try after you think that `django` is not your cup of tea would be `flask` http://flask.pocoo.org/. If you like to go real "indie" on python web framework, try http://www.web2py.com/init/default/download